# trying to setup a pre-push hook using pre-commit

Tags: push, pre-commit.com

I am trying to set up a pre-push hook using pre-commit https://pre-commit.com/
when i make a pre-commit hook it works fine like before commit all the checks work but in case of push no hook runs
This is how my .pre-commit-config-yaml looks like in case of push

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: Test
        name: Test
        stages: [push]
        entry: python3 test.py
        language: system
        types: [python]
```

Does anyone know what am doing wrong?

Comment: did you make sure to `pre-commit install --hook-type pre-push`

Comment: i had done this but still it was test running. I created a new repo , added this and did pre-commit install --hook type pre-push its working now.Thanks for the help :) 
  @AnthonySottile

Comment: one more thing do you know how the structure of my test.py should be, now its returning " passed " every-time, what should i do so that when a particular condition comes it fails

Comment: From [creating new hooks](https://pre-commit.com/#new-hooks): > The hook must exit nonzero on failure or modify files in the working directory

Comment: Got it thanks a lot